# Object stream I/O issue, client object not updated

Tags: java, sockets, object, stream

i'm working a client-server based game. The game is mainly caracterized by a Grid object which must be synchronized between clients. To do that I use the Object I/O Streams over Sockets.

However i encounter an issue during the synchronization process. The Grid is sent and recieved by all clients but its state is not modified after the first upload to each client.

I mean by that that clients do recieve the object in its present state when they connect but subsequent receiptions (initiated by either another client connection or previous client moves) don't present any modification over the initial sent state...

here are (stripped-down) snippets of the server side code:

```
while(true) //continuously accept new connections
     {
     //wait incoming connection, and accept it   
     Socket newSocket = serverListener.accept(); 

     //create player details and save it in hashtable
     Player newPlayer = new Player(newSocket); //streams saved here
     Players.put(newPlayer); 

     //update all clients
     sendGridToAll(); 
     }
```

The Player class constructor:

```
public Player(Socket s) throws IOException
    {
    this.Tx         = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    this.Rx         = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    }
```

The SendToAll method:

```
public void sendGridToAll()
    {
    synchronized(Players) //do nothing while players HT is being modified
        {
        for(Enumeration e = Players.elements(); e.hasMoreElements(); )
            {
            Player tmpPlayer = (Player)e.nextElement();
            ObjectOutputStream tmpTx = tmpPlayer.getTx();

            try {
                tmpTx.writeObject(grid);
                }
            catch(IOException ex) 
                {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                }                
            }
        print.log("Grid update sent");
        }
    }
```

and here is the client side snippet handling the object reception (ran in a thread):

```
public void run()
    {
    ObjectInputStream RX = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());   

    while(true)
        {
        try 
            {
            RX_grid = (Grid)RX.readObject();
            }

        catch (IOException ex) 
            {
            print.log("IO Error");
            ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) 
            {
            print.log("Bad grid class UID");
            }

        finally
            {
            print.log("grid recieved");
            c.updateGui(RX_grid);
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: *(not an answer to your question, hence the comment)*...  One question you should ask yourself, regarding your game, is this: *"How would I code a replayer to replay the last played game?"*. If the replayer cannot be done in a few lines of code then your design is too complex. For anything but massively multiplayer games you should focus on exchanging user inputs, not game states. That's how blockbusters games like StarCraft 2 have tiny replay files: they simply store the user inputs and the time at which the server received them. Then the client(s) reproduce the state from these.

Comment: thank you for your comment. I got what you meant, but for the purpose of this little game, a server-centric approach seemed easier to do. Pros: lightweight client only consisting of refreshing a GUI.  Cons: higher bandwidth and IO operations needed.